# Tensor Product "commutes" with ring homomorphism

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Suppose $R,S$ are (unital and commutative) rings and $\phi:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of rings so we can view $S$ as an $R$-module. Let $A,B$ be $S$-modules, so using $\phi$ we can also view them as $R$-modules. We can now do two operations to get two $R$-modules.

We can do $A\otimes_{R} B$ or we can do $A\otimes_{S} B$ to get an $S$-module and then using $\phi$ we can view this as an $R$-module.

My question is: are these two $R$-modules isomorphic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't in general be isomorphic.

The easiest way to produce a counterexample is with vector spaces. For instance $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}$ is one-dimensional as a complex vector space and thus two-dimensional as a real space, while $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$ is four-dimensional.